# API Routing Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, api, laravel-5

I have basic controller, where I want it to receive any json request. Am new to api routing. I get Sorry No Page Found When I use POST MAN. First I tested it on GET and made it call a simple return but throws the error."Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."
I removed the api prefix in the RouteServiceProvider.php and to no success.I put my demo controller

Routing api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/


Route::get('/test_api/v1', 'TestController@formCheck');
```

TestController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
  public function formCheck(){
    return "YES !!!";
  }

  public function formPost(Request $request)
  {
    $formData = $request->all();
    return response()->json($formData, 201);

  }
}
```

Comment: Don't you forget this : `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` ?

Comment: What url did you try to hit? All files under `api.php` have an `/api/` prefix, so you'd need to hit `www.app.com/api/test_api/v1`.

Comment: @Phiter am trying to hit /test_api/v1 just try my my first method formCheck, on my post man localhost:8000/test_api/v1

Comment: Add `/api` before `/test_api`

Answer (score 0):

In the app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php.

Remove prefix('api') & it shuld look like this.

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
```